# How to route local traffic to LAN/WIFI on Android 11 with VPN enabled? (Rooted)

Tags: root-access, wifi-hotspot, vpn, android-11, firewall

I have a rooted Android 11 device and I use a VPN app with the option Block connections without VPN enabled. This prevents any apps on my phone from communicating with my PC on the same LAN/WIFI network. For example, I can't use `VoiceMeeter VBAN` or `Asus Armoury Crate` apps from my phone.

Is there a way I can set up routing rules or firewall rules on my phone so that local traffic bypasses the VPN block and goes through the LAN/WIFI network?

What I have tried so far:

•  I have used the split tunneling feature, but it didn't work.

•  I have used the AFWall+ app to allow LAN/WIFI access for some apps, but it also didn't work.

I appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Did you ask the developer of the VPN app? I think Android's VPN API allows to exclude subnets from going through VPN.

Comment: Dup of unanswered [previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248207/218526).

Comment: @IrfanLatif I totally forgot about that, is there a way to merge this with that one or get rid of the old one and keep this one?

Comment: You can delete a question. But better leave it to mods. They can merge.